# How to run python program by bypassing compiled stage

Tags: python

Just curious to know that is it possible to run python program in fully interpreted way where compilation can be skipped

Comment: Yes... Open a REPL session and code away.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question fully, due to its vagueness, would require a more careful answer than I have time for, but for the record:

- The CPython implementation compiles source modules into bytecodes.
- When a module is imported, the interpreter looks for a compiled bytecode
  file newer than the source, and uses it if found
- Otherwise the interpreter attempts to write the module's compiled bytecode
  where it will be found on future imports - inability to write the file is
  not an error.
- The bytecode is interpreted by the `eval` loop of the interpreter, and not
  translated into machine code.

Other implementations have other characteristics.

The PyPy implementation of Python that optimises uses JIT techniques to compile Python to executable machine code, but I do not know whether it makes any attempt to cache the JIT-ed code. I suspect it would be unwise to do so, since the optimisations are highly likely to be different each run.

The IronPython implementation compiles into .NET CLR bytecode, which I believe can be subjected to further optimisations.

Jython targets the Java Virtual Machine bytecode, and many JVM implementations apply JIT techniques, again on a per-run basis.

Comment: Ah, good idea mentioning other Python implementations. I perhaps incorrectly assumed the OP was referring specifically to CPython only. +1

Comment: People often are, but the question might have been either about caching bytecode or compilation to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **you are referring to the default implementation of Python - CPython**. **You can't skip compilation**

When you run the command:

```
python <script-name>.py
```

Python (in a very broad and basic sense) does the following steps:

1. Python first parses you code file. The result is an abstract syntax
   tree(a.k.a AST).
2. The AST is then passed to the Python compiler. The Python compiler
   generates the bytecode for the Python virtual machine.
3. The virtual machine then executed the code.

The second step is crucial in the Python interpreter process. Without it, your stuck with an AST and the virtual machine has nothing to execute. Compilation is a necessary process. It's not optional, **it's mandatory**.